# Kafka consumer read the value as String or ByteArray or Json even we send data as object only why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Here you can find controller that send data with String Key and Json Value ..

I am trying to understand why the consumer consider the value sometimes as String other times Json or byteArry
my Controller :

```
@RestController
```

public class HelloKafkaController {

```
private static final Logger logger =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloKafkaController.class);

private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template;
private final String topicName;
private final int messagesPerRequest;
private CountDownLatch latch;

public HelloKafkaController(
        final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template,
        @Value("${tpd.topic-name}") final String topicName,
        @Value("${tpd.messages-per-request}") final int messagesPerRequest) {
    this.template = template;
    this.topicName = topicName;
    this.messagesPerRequest = messagesPerRequest;
}

@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello() throws Exception {
    latch = new CountDownLatch(messagesPerRequest);
    IntStream.range(0, messagesPerRequest)
            .forEach(i -> this.template.send(topicName, String.valueOf(i),
                    new PracticalAdvice("A Practical Advice", i))
            );
    latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    logger.info("All messages received");
    return "Hello Kafka!";
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "advice-topic", clientIdPrefix = "json",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void listenAsObject(ConsumerRecord<String, PracticalAdvice> cr,
                           @Payload PracticalAdvice payload) {
    logger.info("Logger 1 [JSON] received key {}: Type [{}] | Payload: {} | Record: {}", cr.key(),
            typeIdHeader(cr.headers()), payload, cr.toString());
    latch.countDown();
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "advice-topic", clientIdPrefix = "string",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerStringContainerFactory")
public void listenasString(ConsumerRecord<String, String> cr,
                           @Payload String payload) {
    logger.info("Logger 2 [String] received key {}: Type [{}] | Payload: {} | Record: {}", cr.key(),
            typeIdHeader(cr.headers()), payload, cr.toString());
    latch.countDown();
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "advice-topic", clientIdPrefix = "bytearray",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerByteArrayContainerFactory")
public void listenAsByteArray(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> cr,
                              @Payload byte[] payload) {
    logger.info("Logger 3 [ByteArray] received key {}: Type [{}] | Payload: {} | Record: {}", cr.key(),
            typeIdHeader(cr.headers()), payload, cr.toString());
    latch.countDown();
}

private static String typeIdHeader(Headers headers) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(headers.spliterator(), false)
            .filter(header -> header.key().equals("__TypeId__"))
            .findFirst().map(header -> new String(header.value())).orElse("N/A");
}
```

}

logs :

```
    INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 2 [String] received key 0: Type [io.tpd.kafkaexample.PracticalAdvice] | Payload: {"message":"A Practical Advice","identifier":0} | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 2, offset = 44, CreateTime = 1542911788418, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [105, 111, 46, 116, 112, 100, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 46, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101])], isReadOnly = false), key = 0, value = {"message":"A Practical Advice","identifier":0})
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 3 [ByteArray] received key 1: Type [io.tpd.kafkaexample.PracticalAdvice] | Payload: [123, 34, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 34, 58, 34, 65, 32, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 32, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34, 44, 34, 105, 100, 101, 110, 116, 105, 102, 105, 101, 114, 34, 58, 49, 125] | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 0, offset = 44, CreateTime = 1542911788422, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [105, 111, 46, 116, 112, 100, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 46, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101])], isReadOnly = false), key = 1, value = [B@39113414)
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 2 [String] received key 2: Type [io.tpd.kafkaexample.PracticalAdvice] | Payload: {"message":"A Practical Advice","identifier":2} | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 2, offset = 45, CreateTime = 1542911788422, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [105, 111, 46, 116, 112, 100, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 46, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101])], isReadOnly = false), key = 2, value = {"message":"A Practical Advice","identifier":2})
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 3 [ByteArray] received key 5: Type [io.tpd.kafkaexample.PracticalAdvice] | Payload: [123, 34, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 34, 58, 34, 65, 32, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 32, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34, 44, 34, 105, 100, 101, 110, 116, 105, 102, 105, 101, 114, 34, 58, 53, 125] | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 0, offset = 45, CreateTime = 1542911788422, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [105, 111, 46, 116, 112, 100, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 46, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101])], isReadOnly = false), key = 5, value = [B@476e998b)
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 2 [String] received key 3: Type [io.tpd.kafkaexample.PracticalAdvice] | Payload: {"message":"A Practical Advice","identifier":3} | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 2, offset = 46, CreateTime = 1542911788422, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [105, 111, 46, 116, 112, 100, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 46, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101])], isReadOnly = false), key = 3, value = {"message":"A Practical Advice","identifier":3})
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 3 [ByteArray] received key 7: Type [io.tpd.kafkaexample.PracticalAdvice] | Payload: [123, 34, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 34, 58, 34, 65, 32, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 32, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34, 44, 34, 105, 100, 101, 110, 116, 105, 102, 105, 101, 114, 34, 58, 55, 125] | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 0, offset = 46, CreateTime = 1542911788423, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [105, 111, 46, 116, 112, 100, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 46, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101])], isReadOnly = false), key = 7, value = [B@7a229d60)
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 2 [String] received key 9: Type [io.tpd.kafkaexample.PracticalAdvice] | Payload: {"message":"A Practical Advice","identifier":9} | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 2, offset = 47, CreateTime = 1542911788423, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [105, 111, 46, 116, 112, 100, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 46, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101])], isReadOnly = false), key = 9, value = {"message":"A Practical Advice","identifier":9})
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 3 [ByteArray] received key 8: Type [io.tpd.kafkaexample.PracticalAdvice] | Payload: [123, 34, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 34, 58, 34, 65, 32, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 32, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101, 34, 44, 34, 105, 100, 101, 110, 116, 105, 102, 105, 101, 114, 34, 58, 56, 125] | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 0, offset = 47, CreateTime = 1542911788423, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [105, 111, 46, 116, 112, 100, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 46, 80, 114, 97, 99, 116, 105, 99, 97, 108, 65, 100, 118, 105, 99, 101])], isReadOnly = false), key = 8, value = [B@536adff4)
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 1 [JSON] received key 4: Type [N/A] | Payload: PracticalAdvice::toString() {message='A Practical Advice', identifier=4} | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 1, offset = 22, CreateTime = 1542911788422, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = 4, value = PracticalAdvice::toString() {message='A Practical Advice', identifier=4})
INFO 15292 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : Logger 1 [JSON] received key 6: Type [N/A] | Payload: PracticalAdvice::toString() {message='A Practical Advice', identifier=6} | Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = advice-topic, partition = 1, offset = 23, CreateTime = 1542911788422, serialized key size = 1, serialized value size = 47, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = 6, value = PracticalAdvice::toString() {message='A Practical Advice', identifier=6})
INFO 15292 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] i.tpd.kafkaexample.HelloKafkaController  : All messages received
```

Comment: JSON is a String. Strings are UTF8 decoded byte arrays. Why _shouldnt_ all listeners be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 consumers , @KafkaLitseners,  threads reading from the topic "advice-topic", you ask the messages to be deserialzed as JSON , STRING , BYTEARRAY

`java.lang.String`
`clientIdPrefix`
When provided, overrides the client id property in the consumer factory configuration

What are you trying to achieve?

Kafka only knows byte array, it is the deserializer which you defines tells it with which "glasses" to look on the data

Comment: What I am trying to understand is , we have 3 listeners each responsible to  deserialize  one type of values which is Byte Array , String and JSON ... 
in my case the listener who handle JSON Only should be triggered  why all of them triggered

Comment: Where do you think you set which listener will handle only specfic type of message?

Comment: Yes Ran , this what i think about

Comment: I meant,  where in the code you think you had set a condition on the listener? Kafka does not know the "type" of data inside it

Comment: okay I got it ,  so what's the benefit of having listeners  with different deserializer